# Where can you get this scrollable/expandable bar View/Resrouce?

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design, android-resources

Where can I find this View/Resource? I've seen it on several apps. It's supposed to expose some hidden layouts.

Here is the View/Resource I talked about:

[image]

And here, on the gray background, you can also see the hidden layouts:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A child View of a `CoordinatorLayout` can have Standard Bottom Sheet characteristics enabled by using `BottomSheetBehavior`. In doing so, the bottom anchoring, drag up/down gesture support and animated state transitions and more are handled for us.

The attributes:

`behavior_hideable`: Determines whether or not the sheet can be hidden when using a drag down gesture (bearing in mind that it can always be hidden programmatically). The default value is false for Standard Bottom Sheets and true for Modal Bottom Sheets.

`behavior_draggable`: Determines whether or not the sheet can be collapsed/expanded when using a drag gesture (bearing in mind that a custom way to expand/collapse the sheet will need to be implemented). The default value is true.

`behavior_skipCollapsed`: Determines whether or not the collapsed state should be ignored when hiding the sheet. This does not affect if behavior_hideable is not set to true. The default value is false.

`behavior_fitToContents`: Determines whether or not the height of the expanded sheet wraps its contents. Alternatively, it expands in two stages: half the height of the parent container, full height of the parent container. The default value is true.

`behavior_halfExpandedRatio`: Determines the height of the sheet (as a ratio of the parent container height) when in a half-expanded state. This does not affect if behavior_fitToContents is not set to false and should be greater than the peek height. The default value is 0.5 (the recommended ratio in the Material Guidelines).

`behavior_expandedOffset`: Determines the offset of the sheet from the top of the parent container when in an expanded state. This does not affect if behavior_fitToContents is not set to false and should be greater than the offset when in a half-expanded state. The default value is 0dp (the top of the sheet matches the top of the parent container).

`behavior_peekHeight`: The initial “peek” (collapsed state) height of the sheet. The default value is auto, which sets the peek height at the 16:9 ratio keyline of the parent container. A dimension (or pixel value, programmatically) can otherwise be used.
[image]

Now the implementation:

**layout_main.xml**

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
            
            
                <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                    app:elevation="0dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            
                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                        />
                </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
            
            
            
            
            
            
                <!-- Adding bottom sheet after main content -->
                <include
                    layout="@layout/bottomsheet_layout" />
            
            </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**bottomsheet_layout.xml**

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            
            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:behavior_hideable="false"
                app:behavior_peekHeight="115dp"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">
            
            
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
            
            
                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="110dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
            
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/frame_curved_border_top" />
            
                        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:background="@color/white">
            
            
            
            
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
                                android:text=" Siliguri - Gangtok   (6123)"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_bold"
                                android:text="8:00 AM  - 6:00 AM"
                                android:textSize="14sp"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
            
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
                                android:text="STNM Government"
                                android:textSize="13sp"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView14"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
            
            
            
            
                        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
                    </FrameLayout>
            
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
            
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_bold"
                            android:text="Journey Updates"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />
            
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                            android:drawableTint="@color/light_grey"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
                            android:text="Driver started the journey"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />
            
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="2dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:background="#ddd" />
            
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                            android:drawableTint="@color/light_grey"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
                            android:text="Driver has left the bus stop (SNT)"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />
            
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="2dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:background="#ddd" />
            
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                            android:drawableTint="@color/light_grey"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
                            android:text="Driver is on the way"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />
            
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="2dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:background="#ddd" />
            
            
                    </LinearLayout>
            
                </LinearLayout>
            
            
            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

You can use this as **frame_curved_border_top.png**

[image]

Now you have other options like the `MotionLayout` to achieve the same result in Android, it is up to you to decide. And if you wanted just a simple `FragmentDialog` implementation without the drag effect, I shall update the answer with that as well. Please select it as an answer if this helps.